# I need a double if statement in php with different variables

Tags: php, if-statement, pdo

I've tried this so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $connectionPDO->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$type = $row['rights'];

if(check_login_status() == false)
{
   header("Location:error.php");
   exit;
}
```

If the entry in the column "rights" for the specific user is "user" and if there is no one logged in then it must redirect to error.php. So far this doesn't work. It still shows the page if i'm logged in with a user account. Hopefully I'm specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra piece of information in the `header()` function and also to add a `exit;` after the `header()` otherwise execution will just continue within this code fragment.

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$type = $row['rights'];

if(check_login_status() == false && $type == "user")
{
    header("Location: error.php");
    exit;
}
```

Of course the proper execution of the `if` statement depends on things you have not specified like does `check_login_status()` actually return `false` and have you checked that `$type` actually is `"user"`.

Try this as a test :

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$type = $row['rights'];

// just testing
$type = "user";

if(check_login_status() == false && $type == "user")
{
    header("Location: error.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem really lies with the double if statement. I changed it single (only the check_login_status part) and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well have you checked the actual value of `$type`

Comment: the string "user" is grabbed from a database entry with a specific ID. So if the entry in the column "rights" is "user"  then it gives it that value to the variable $type.

Comment: But what if the data in the database value is actually `"user "` or `" user"` or something not exactly 4 chars long = to `user`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `if` syntax so now you have to check the data it is processing!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong syntax:

```
header("Location:error.php");
```

Comment: Indeed I did. I changed it and it's still not working.

Comment: It's  working. the solution was a single if statement: if ($type != "admin"){ header('Location: error.php') exit; This way  if i'm not logged in the $type is not "admin". So it redirects. Thanks for the answers. How do I close a question by the way?